# Can I install @angular/cli@4.2.2 locally without downgrading the latest @angular/cli@6.2.0 version globally?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

[My global angular version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY0pJ.jpg)

Globally i have @angular/cli@6.2.0 installed, the lastest version, but I would like to install @angular/cli@4.2.2 locally just for this one project, how do I do that without downgrading the global version?

Comment: You can specify the version in your `package.json` and run `npm install`

Comment: @Wernerson Yes, that works, but that way I have too many things to change. Is there a way to create a project using particular version of angular straight away? I tried installing npm install @angular/cli@1.4.6 in a specific folder, and it installs something and it reports that my local version is lower than my global version, but that the local version will be used nevertheless, but nothing gets created inside the folder itself, no json file, whatsoever.

Comment: I also tried using ng new project command inside of that particular folder, where I already installed @angular/cli@1.4.6, supposedly successfully, and I get the following error: Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined, and nothing gets created inside of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can only execute the `ng new` command from outside of an Angular project. So it uses the global version.

Any of the other `ng` commands are executed within an Angular project and will then use the local version.

You can, however, try `npx` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) It allows you to run any npm package.

An easier option may be to downgrade your global Angular CLI ... use the `ng new` command, and then globally reinstall the current Angular CLI version.

NOTE: Angular 4.2.2 (as shown in the title of this question) was released on June 12, 2017. https://github.com/angular/angular/releases?after=4.3.1

The Angular CLI v1.1.2 was released on June 15, 2017 ... so that *MAY* be the version you need for Angular 4.2.2?  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases?after=v1.3.0-beta.1

From the Angular team: `Theoretically 1.7.x should work with 4.x.x, but it's a little ambiguous, which part of the reason we synced the majors.`

Comment: In addition, there is no `@angular/cli` v4.2.2. From Angular v2 -v5 the cli was version 1.x.x. It wasn't until the release of Angular v6 did the Angular team synch up all their packages, hence Angular/cli v6.x.x. If the OP (I assume) wants to use Angular/core v4.2.2 they will need to find out what CLI works best for that version.

Comment: Yep! Thanks for catching that. I'll look up the version and update my reply.

Comment: Is the command for uninstalling angular globally so that I can install earlier version: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli?